# LINQ - GroupBy over many-to-many relation

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, many-to-many

How to write GroupBy clause which will retrieve multiple records from many to many relation?

I have following structure:

```
 public class Failure{
    public virtual int IdFailure { get; set; }
    public virtual Workstation Workstation{ get; set; }
 }

 public class Workstation{
    public virtual int IdWorkstation { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<WorksocketWorkstation> WorksocketWorkstation { get; set; }
 }

 public class WorksocketWorkstation{
    public virtual int IdWorksocketWorkstation{ get; set; }
    public virtual Worksocket Worksocket{ get; set; }
    public virtual Workstation Workstation{ get; set; }
 }

 public class Worksocket {
    public virtual int IdWorksocket { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<WorksocketWorkstation> WorksocketWorkstation { get; set; }
 }
```

What I want to do is to group Failures by related Worksockets, including "duplicates" resulting from many-to-many relation, so if I have a Failure occuring on Workstation assigned to three Worksockets, I want it to be accounted for each of these Worksockets. Currently I'm using something like this to get my results:

```
GetFailures().GroupBy(g => g.Workstation.WorksocketWorkstation.FirstOrDefault().Worksocket.IdWorksocket)
```

But since I'm using `FirstOrDefault`, each Failure is accounted only for single Worksocket. I've tried to use `SelectMany` instead or get the data from the Worksockets side, based on the similar questions that have been already answered here, but I can't wrap my head around any of the ideas and adjust them to my needs, so any help or explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you don't have a real relation from failure to worksocket. For example if you have two failures related to two different workstations. When do you want those failures to be grouped? When workstations has at least one the same worksocket? Or you want to show all worksockets and put into it all failures that might occur on it. Just might because you don't know exactly - you know only the workstation.

Comment: Adding the currently missing navigation property `public  ICollection<Failure> Failures { get; set; }` to `Workstation` should give you better idea how to do what you need starting from `Worksockets` side.

Comment: @IvanStoev it's in my project, I just simplified it here for the clarity's sake. You're right - if I'd be trying to do that from Worksockets side it would be pretty much necessary, however in my case that's a last resort solution and I want to avoid it if possible. I'm already doing similar grouping from Failures side based on other parameters.

Comment: @PavelAgarkov "you want to show all worksockets and put into it all failures that might occur on it." - that. I'm retrieving data for chart showing how many failures occured in every worksocket.

Comment: The point was that in that case you don't need grouping at all. But if you insist on grouping, first "duplicate" the data and then "group". e.g. start from here `GetFailures().SelectMany(f => f.Workstation.WorksocketWorkstation, (f, ww) => new { Failure = f, Workstation = ww.Workstation })`, followed by `GroupBy` and `Select`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
GetFailures().SelectMany(g => g.Workstation.WorksocketWorkstation)
             .GroupBy(g => g.Worksocket.IdWorksocket)
```

Comment: It works! Many thanks. My mistake when using `SelectMany` was that I tried to do that inside `GroupBy` clause.

Comment: Great answer, it's not exactly like my problem, but it helped me to fix it!